# Where did this explosion occur?

Tags: far-cry-5

In one of Far Cry 5's ending, there was a nuclear bomb detonated in the background. Where is this located in the in-game map? Is it possible to even get there or noclip to the location?

See this video for the ending in question:

Answer (score 1):

Well I was kind of disappointed with the "good" ending so I did some investigating in-game after the credits. The first nuke that detonates is somewhere over the mountain in John's region, literally right next to his closed silo near the bunker and the "YES" sign. I couldn't find a nuke or anything but I don't think it'd give me that option if I already beat the game. I know for sure Faith has a silo near her bunker too and we see 3 nukes go off before crashing, I'm not sure where Jacob's silo is located if he has one.. This could all be wishful thinking, hoping for an actual good ending. We know for a fact there are silos but no one knows where the nukes are or if they even exist in-game, the ending is left open for our own interpretations.